# StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml/escapeHtml4 inconsistent between commons-lang and commons-lang3

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

unit test shows StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml/escapeHtml4 don't produce same results.

trying to upgrade commons-lang(2.6) to commons-lang3(3.9) and found parity-mismatch in escapeHtml/escapeHtml4 methods.

```java
for (String s : Stream.generate(()-> RandomStringUtils.random(100)).limit(100).toArray(String[]::new)) {
    String oldVersion =
        org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s);

    String newVersion =
        org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(s);

    Assertions.assertEquals(oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

i would have expected the commons-lang3 StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4() to produce the same results as commons-lang StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml().  granted, this test is over the full unicode range but still...

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :&#57572;&#38722;&#6951;&#46268;&#49020;&#14235;&#12033;&#23546;&#464;&#63262;&#24364;&#28595;&#55776;&#56400;&#64402;&#5905;&#25570;&#16932;&#43930;&#32819;&#6363;&#27856;&#19126;&#55455;&#56399;&#45697;&#14348;&#37578;&#21122;&#33603;&#10058;&#55372;&#56361;&#45800;&#41102;&#27388;&#13568;&#19452;&#32121;&#19644;&#46001;&#48986;&#53596;&#9737;&#38022;&#58982;&#51844;&#3410;&#19927;&#60896;&#15016;&#58795;&#55344;&#57177;&#38010;&#61906;&#24009;&#8012;&#19538;&#58070;&#54739;&#43519;&#59479;&#14421;&#55292;&#14768;&#59510;&#9644;&#18368;&#10760;&#42323;&#8650;&#49303;&#1351;&#13877;&#5151;&#34483;&#55891;&#56391;&#10170;&#52943;&#54414;&#52020;&#24458;&#54443;&#7570;&#21692;&#33464;&#5662;&#35760;&#6350;&#7978;&#43215;&#38488;&#1169;&#32794;&#16522;&#45386;&#7513;&#38620;
Actual   :靂ᬧ뒼뽼㞛⼁寺ǐ弬澳ﮒᜑ揢䈤ꮚ耳ᣛ泐䪶늁㠌鋊劂荃❊단ꂎ櫼㔀䯼絹䲼뎱뽚템☉钆쪄൒䷗㪨鑺巉Ὄ䱒헓꧿㡕퟼㦰▬䟀⨈ꕓ⇊삗Շ㘵ᐟ蚳➺컏풎쬴徊풫ᶒ咼芸ᘞ记ᣎἪ꣏陘ґ耚䂊녊ᵙ雜
```

are these chars not escaped in HTML4 any longer?  doesn't that depend on your encoding?  is there a way to force commons-lang3 to behave like commons-lang in this regard?

Comment: The "inconsistency" (certainly a difference) is not between `lang` and `lang3` but between methods `escapeHtml()` and `escapeHtml4()`. Otherwise it sounds like by simply updating to `lang3` your code would start to behave differently (which in my opinion would be bad). Updating your code to `lang3` would break your compilation allowing you to notice that the old method is gone, that a new one is there, and to evaluate if and how you should use the new method. Asking about their differences is great but it's not good to claim "inconsistencies" between them.